# How to use \newrobustcmd and \NewDocumentCommand with hyperref in section titles

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, etoolbox, xparse

How can `\newrobustcmd` and `NewDocumentCommand` be used in section titles with `hyperref` enabled? The MWE below shows that, while the rendered PDF looks correct, the bookmarks do not show the macro contents.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\testA}[0]{world}
\newrobustcmd{\testB}[0]{world}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testC}{}{world}

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello \testA}
    \section{Hello \testB}
    \section{Hello \testC}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting pdf]

The `MWE.out` file looks as follows.

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{Hello world}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{Hello }{}% 2
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.3}{Hello }{}% 3
```

Comment: The purpose of `\newrobustcmd` is to not expand the macro in `\edef`, which is what `hyperref` does for bookmarks; `\NewDocumentCommand` does the same. So what you get is expected. Why should you define those macros as robust?

Comment: Perhaps `\section{Hello \protect\testa}` for the `\newcommand` version  is a bypass in order to prevent breaking apart during the writing process to the `.aux` file concerning the ToC and still having the expanded `\testa` in the bookmarks (assuming that `\testa` expands to valid content for the bookmarks, however)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `\newcommand` you define an expandable macro (`\def`) while with `\newrobustcmd` and `\NewDocumentCommand` you define an engine-protected macro (`\protected\def`). The content of bookmarks gets expanded while the bookmark strings are being built but protected macros can't get expanded so the tokens `\testB` and `\testC` in your MWE end up as they are in the bookmarks. `hyperref` doesn't know what to do with them so it discards them.

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\testB' on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\testC' on input line 14.
```

So if you really need protected macros you have two choices:

- use `\section{Hello \texorpdfstring{\testB}{world}}` in the document or
- add simpler expandable definitions in the preamble after loading `hyperref` which will be used in the bookmarks

  ```
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \def\testB{world}%
    \def\testC{wor‌​ld}%
  }
  ```