# Italic citation numbers and normal font brackets with biblatex numeric or numeric-comp style

Tags: biblatex

**Problem:** I would like for the citation numbers of a `numeric` or `numeric-comp` style biblatex to be in italics but not the enclosing brackets. My efforts thus far have failed. I would not like for the bibliography entries to be modified in anyway if this is possible.

**What I have tried:** I tried modifying the code in the MWEB as such:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens\mkbibemph]
```

and

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibemph\mkbibparens]
```

Both of which made the citation number appear outside the bracket. I also tried the answer by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252526/245306) which had no effect (I am not even sure if it would with biblatex).

**How it currently looks:**

[image]

**How I would like it to look:**

[image]

My vision may not be the best but I believe that the brackets enclosing the citation numbers are normal and not in italics.

**MWEB:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Change in-text citations to round brackets - moewe: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341043/245306
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibparens]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and I am compiling with:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. The wrapper command is a good idea to do this, but you need to make sure that the command you give there absorbs one argument. `\mkbibparens\mkbibemph` doesn't do that, because it essentially expands to `\mkbibparens{\mkbibemph}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibparensitalic}[1]{%
  \mkbibparens{\mkbibitalic{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparensitalic]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibparensitalic]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\cites{sigfridsson}{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (2) (2, 1) [numbers italic; brackets upright]]

---

The same strategy can be used for most styles, but if you switch styles you may need to make sure that the definition of `\cite` you have here is compatible with your style.

Specifically for `numeric-comp` the code would have to look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibparensitalic}[1]{%
  \mkbibparens{\mkbibitalic{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparensitalic]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibparensitalic]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\cites{sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly +1. To anyone who may come across this who, like myself, has never seen `\newrobustcmd` before [this contains a brief explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373183/245306).

Comment: If I change from `numeric` to `numeric-comp` (to use ranges) it says that `\cite is undefined` - is this a new question or does the existing answer contain a trivial solution that could be edited please if possible for both numeric and numeric-comp? I understand its a related but different style and may change the question entirely. Will delete this comment if new question is required, thanks.

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor See the edited answer, please.

Comment: I changed the title and intro to include `numeric-comp` as well so the question and answers fit better and are easier to search for, thank you for your help and advice.